# Dapper query for nullable decimal field not working

Tags: c#, orm, dapper

I have a table that contains a nullable decimal(12,4) column. When I query like this:

```
const string sqlQuery = "SELECT Id From DummyTable WHERE Price = @Price";

var sqlParameter = new { Price = (decimal?)null };
```

this query returns 0 record. But when I change the query as:

```
const string sqlQuery = "SELECT Id From DummyTable WHERE Price IS NULL;
```

this syntax works. So how can I query the nullable decimal column with parameters? Thanks.

Comment: don't you have to use `IS` with null, can you actually use `=`

Comment: `= NULL` doesn't work for me in TSQL. It has to be `IS NULL` that is probably where your problem is...

Comment: What if I want to use the same function for Price = 12.3 or similar parameters? @CallumLinington

Comment: you'll have to write a special case for nulls. when you are equating numbers, their assumed default is 0, they are non nullable types for a reason, because we always "know" they start at 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very sexy, but you can try something like this:

```
[Test]
public void NullParamTest()
{
    _connection.Execute(@"drop table foo; 
                          create table foo(id int not null,price decimal(12, 4) null)");
    _connection.Execute("insert into foo values(1, null)");
    _connection.Execute("insert into foo values(2, 12.99)");

    const string sql = @"select price from foo 
                        where coalesce(price, -1) = coalesce(@Price, -1)";

    var result = _connection.Query<decimal?>(sql,new { Price = (decimal?)null }).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.That(result, Is.Null);

    result = _connection.Query<decimal?>(sql,new { Price = 12.99 }).FirstOrDefault();
    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(12.99));
}
```

Assuming "Price" cannot be negative...